# PHP - how can we send multiple Images using Whatsapp Cloud Api

Tags: php, facebook, whatsapp

I am trying to send multiple images with Whatsapp Cloud API. Using PHP, I am able to send one image and normal text messages  successfully.

```
{
   

 "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "to": "NUMBER",
  "type": "template",
  "template": {
    "name": "booking_confirmation_details",
    "language": {
      "code": "en"
    },
    "components": [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "parameters": [
        
          {
            "type": "image",
            "image": {
              "link": "IMAGE"
            }
          }
          
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

}
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported right now, might be getting in future releases.
Search out for Twilio method to send multiple images at once but ofcourse for that you will have to use Twilio api, a wrapper over whatsapp cloud api.

There could be a work around which I myself have not used anytime but you can try. Send multiple http request to user with single image per request.